# Acquire token for Graph API using MSAL?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to use MSAL (1.0.304142221-alpha) to acquire a token for the Microsoft Graph API, using the client credentials flow. My code looks like so:

```
var confidentialClientApp = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, redirectUri, new ClientCredential(clientSecret), null);
var token = confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "Mail.Read" }, string.Empty).Result;
```

The 2nd line throws an exception: "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope Mail.Read is not valid.".
The [Graph API reference](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_get) appears to cite "Mail.Read" as the required scope.

The application in Azure AD is a Web Application with a single key. The application has the "Read mail in all mailboxes" application permission set for Microsoft Graph.

Could anyone shed any light as to what is going on? Thankyou :)

Comment: Did you finally manage to get this working? Having the same issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the v2 of the Azure AD endpoints do not yet support app-only tokens. For the time being you are restricted to use delegated tokens. We hope to enable app-only tokens soon, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's available now!

Comment: Is there any tutorial available for this? I am using angular 5 , I get the token using msal loginRedirect but when i use that token to do a GET call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me with authorization bearer token header, I get "Access token validation failure.". How do I resolve this?